# Select2 doesn't work on bootstrap popover form?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, bootstrap-popover

I have a `table` one row contains around 30 `td` for each `td` I open a popover where I will be showing my form because I want to show for which `td` they enter the values so I have chosen to use bootstrap popover,

[image]

I use `select2` for all the `select` field on popover form. Like this,

```
$(".select2").select2({
   width: '100%',
});
```

But this doesn't seems to be working. `select2` gets applied but `option` is not opening at all.

I also reinitialised the `select2` like this,

```
$('body').on('shown.bs.popover', function (e) {
    $(".select2").select2("destroy").select2();
});
```

but still the same issue.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/42303/)**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think select2 option did show, but it appeared behind popover container.
Maybe you can try to change select2 `z-index` like below:

```
.select2-dropdown {
   z-index: 9001; //or try higher
}
```